# Attempting to change server after selecting "Remember permanently" when running project on netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, vaadin

Currently, I am building a Vaadin Web Application Project on Netbeans. When looking up how to run the project, I followed the steps on this site:

https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/getting-started/getting-started-netbeans.html

However, I suppose I rashly selected "Remember permanently" after selecting my (Glassfish) server; now, I want to use a different server that I've added (since I realized that the old server was using an occupied HTTP port). However, when I select Run Project in Netbeans, I don't even get the option to select the deployment server anymore (which makes sense due to me selecting Remember permanently). How do I regain access to the "Change Deployment Server" menu (shown at the bottom)?

[Link to image because I don't have enough reputation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGoM5.png)

Also, as for what I've tried, I've tried removing the old server from the Netbeans menu (Tools->Servers) and also removing the local domain that the project was deploying to, but neither of those worked and the program STILL goes to the old port.

Answer (score 1):

To change the server you want to run your application on:

- Select the project in the **Projects** panel.
- Right-click and select **Properties** from the popup menu.
- Select **Run** in the **Categories** list.
- Pick the server you want to use from the **Server** drop list and click **OK**.

[image: RunProperties]

The next time you run the application it will use your new server.

If the only problem is a port clash you could change the configuration of one of your application servers to use a different port, but the approach described above is simpler.